# SonarQube: see details of failed tests

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube

In SonarQube 5.6.6, I can see on http://example.com/component_measures/metric/test_failures/list?id=myproject that my unit test results were successfully imported. This is indicated by

> Unit Test Failures: 1

which I produced by a fake failing test.

I also see the filename of the failing test class in a long list, and I see the number of failed tests (again: 1).

But I can't find any more information: which method, stack trace, stdout/err, just everything which is also included in the `build/reports/test/index.html` files generated by gradle? Clicking to the list entry points me to the code and coverage view, but I can't find any indicator, which test failed.

Am I doing something wrong in the frontend, is it a configuration problem, or am I looking for a feature which doesn't exist in SonarQube?

**This is how it looks currently:**

http://example.com/component_measures/domain/Coverage: Here I see that one test failed:

[image: Sonar Measures-Coverage]

http://example.com/component_measures/metric/test_success_density/list: I can see which file it is:

[image: Sonar Unit Test Errors]

But clicking on the line above only points me to the source file. Below the test which "failed". There is no indication that this test failed. And I can't find any way to see stack trace or the name of the failed test method:

[image: Sonar Code View]

Btw: The page of the first screenshot show Information about unit tests. But if the failing test is an integration test, I don't even see these numbers

**Update**

Something like this is probably what I'm looking for:
[image] (found on https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/individual-test-coverage-sonarqube-jacoco/)

I never saw such a view on my installation, don't know how to get it and if it is implemented in the current version.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your current SonarQube version

Comment: Build failures and unit test failures are not in the focus of SonarQube. SonarQube kind of "expects" that your project is compilable and all tests are green. You should use other tools for those tasks.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Did you read the first line?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were contrasting behavior in 5.6.6 to your _current_ version.

Comment: No, this is my version, and the only version I know from SonarQube. So what I describe is more what I expect to see as a novice, not something that I already saw. I never used Sonar before

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam. Is there any way to get details of unit test case failure in sonarqube? Is it available in developer or enterprise version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Test execution details is a deprecated feature Sonar Qube 5.6

If you install older version such as Sonar Qube 4.x, we will get following screen which provides test case result details.

[image]

But this screen itself has been removed.
Ref # https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-657

Basically the issue is Unit test case details report requires links back to source code files. But now the unit test cases are only linked to assemblies.

Comment: Nice one (not nice from sonar though). Do you have a link with more detailed information about the deprecation? A short search didn't help me.

Comment: Unfortunately no. We had this as a major road blocker since we moved to Sonar Qube 6.7 and now the team is not able to find failed test cases details.
Industry has moved towards executing test cases in Jenkins which provide a great UI and detailed description of success and failure.

Comment: Yes, that's true that test result can normaly also be seen in another system too, but it's somehow weird to see that there were failing tests but not which (and to know that all the necessary information is already in sonar). Thx anyway